# Link anchors working only once in iPhone's browser

Tags: iphone, html, webkit, mobile-webkit

I'm making a mobile interface for my web app, and I'm trying to use anchor links to make navigation easier. My code is similar to this:

```
<a href="#section2">Jump to section 2</a>
... lots of stuff here ...
<h2 id="section2">Section 2</h2>
```

The problem is that the link works only once. So if a user, using his iPhone, taps that link and jumps to section 2, then scrolls back to the top and clicks that link again it won't work. He has to refresh the page.

Is there any way to get around this?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `id`, use `<a name="section2">Section 2</a>`

Comment: I believe everything's slowly moving over to anchoring on the div's ID... not <a> tags.